# How to tune MySQL for restoration from MySQL dump?

Tags: performance, mysql, mysqldump, performance-tuning

My little 5GB database which takes 5 minutes to dump via mysqldump, takes 9 hours to restore. Luckily I found this out during a test-run, not an actual emergency situation.

What are the best parameters to optimize to speed this up?

I have tried the following settings on my server with 2GB of RAM:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=50M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_log_buffer_size=1G
```

The weird thing is that even with these aggressize settings, `top` only shows mysqld is barely using a fraction of the assigned memory:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
4421 mysql     20   0  247m  76m 5992 S   91  3.7   4:09.33 mysqld
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to [compute these numbers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194) before the mysqldump.

Concerning the settings you gave in the question,

```
innodb_log_file_size=1G
```

This setting is WAY TOO BIG!!!

The [`innodb_log_file_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file__size) is supposed to be 25% of [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)

**innodb_log_file_size=128M**

Once you set this in `/etc/my.cnf`, you must do the following to resize your InnoDB log files:

1. `service mysql stop`
2. `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile[01]`
3. `service mysql start`

As for the other setting

```
innodb_log_buffer_size=1G
```

You never want to cache a ton of data in here before sending them to the InnoDB Log Files, especially for mysqldump reloads or heavy transactional COMMITs. The should be an order of magnitude smaller.

```
innodb_log_buffer_size=32M
```

BTW You should disable binary logging before reloading. Otherwise, all the data lands in your binary logs. Please do one of the following:

1. Make this -> `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;` the first line of the mysqldump file.
2. From MySQL command line, run `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;` then run `source < mysqldumpfile >`
3. Comment out log-bin from `/etc/my.cnf` and restart MySQL 5.1, load the mysqldump file, uncomment log-bin, and restart MySQL.

#### UPDATE 2011-07-24 20:30

If you have a mysqldump file `/root/MyData.sql`, you can still run the commands like this

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
source /root/MyData.sql
```

This falls under option 2.

Comment: Some sql files can be awkward to edit and add "SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;"
Instead:
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;" | gzip > sql_log_bin.sql.gz; then run this:
zcat sql_log_bin.sql.gz backup.sql.gz | mysql

Comment: I just want to make sure you are using --opt with the mysqldump utility. This is a HUGE time saver when reloading. without it mysqldump creates the sql file row by row. --opt does: Adds locks, drop and recreate with all create options enabled, temporarily disables the keys for a quick reload and then turns keys back on at the end to rebuild the indexes after the writing is done. It concatenates several rows together in inserts to reduce filesize AND parsing time of each statement (by up to 70%) and enables --quick to reduce the load against the dumping DB when running. reduces load time by 80%

Comment: @ppostma1 --opt is enabled by default. It says so in the documentation already : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt

Comment: I have 4 different flavors of linux running online servers and some distro's mysql package managers disable it! It can be the different between 12 hours to reload a WP database and 8 minutes when its on. I find the managers explanation is "availability of incremental backups". My best understanding is if the server is routinely backed up, it could be off by default. Then the user must manually add the --opt option to specify this is not an incremental backup attempt.

Comment: @ppostma1 Oh that's scary !!! The documentation says it is on by default. My guess is that the distros that do not have `--opt` must have been compiled from source and the option forgotten. I'll definitely keep this issue in my back pocket for any future encounters like this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation with a dump restoration taking too long. In my case I was able to speed up the restoration 3-10 times by postponing the MySQL index creation.

In short, the index is recalculated on every insert. So it's better to calculate the index for the whole table all at once.

Here is an example, how MySQL exports data:

```
CREATE TABLE `SOME_TABLE` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SOME_COLUMN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `OTHER_COLUMN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_SOME_COLUMN` (`SOME_COLUMN`),
  KEY `IDX_OTHER_COLUMN` (`OTHER_COLUMN`)
);

INSERT INTO `SOME_TABLE` (`id`, `SOME_COLUMN`, `OTHER_COLUMN`)
VALUES (...), (...), ... ;
```

If you have millions of rows in a table with indexes it will be restored much longer as if indices were applied after inserts.

You will get higher import speed if you just move index creation statements after inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE `SOME_TABLE` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SOME_COLUMN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `OTHER_COLUMN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `SOME_TABLE` (`id`, `SOME_COLUMN`, `OTHER_COLUMN`)
VALUES (...), (...), ... ;

ALTER TABLE `SOME_TABLE`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `UK_SOME_COLUMN` (`SOME_COLUMN`),
ADD KEY `IDX_OTHER_COLUMN` (`OTHER_COLUMN`);
```

Check [my repository](https://github.com/kokorin/mysql-dump-optimizer) for a simple python script, which does the above transformation.

Comment: This is a great answer which would be useless (vague and non-prescriptive) if it were not accompanied by a link to a Reference Implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is I/O, not memory. If you profile the disk, you'll find it thrashing madly to read and write, especially if it's on the same disk as the backup.

I'd move the file to a different physical drive and see if that helps.